# Fail2ban how to configure custom fail regex filter

Tags: debian, regex, fail2ban, filter

I am running fail2ban on Debian 9 and am trying to create a custom filter to ban an ip after 4 failed attempts.  Can someone help to figure out what I need to put in filter.d and jail.conf in order for this to work. everything I have tried does not work.

This is what I've tried:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^.*INFO .* bad login attempt \(<HOST>\) in tomcat-(?:HTTP|HTTPS)-exec-\d*$
ignoreregex =
```

Here are the logs:

```
1610423968.390 2021-01-11 22:59:28.390/EST: INFO   [uv.login] admin bad login attempt (107.126.50.200) in tomcat-HTTPS-exec-1
1610423970.613 2021-01-11 22:59:30.613/EST: INFO   [uv.login] admin bad login attempt (107.126.50.200) in tomcat-HTTPS-exec-4
1610423972.032 2021-01-11 22:59:32.032/EST: INFO   [uv.login] admin bad login attempt (107.126.50.200) in tomcat-HTTPS-exec-3
1610423973.402 2021-01-11 22:59:33.402/EST: INFO   [uv.login] admin bad login attempt (107.126.50.200) in tomcat-HTTPS-exec-5
1610424009.770 2021-01-11 23:00:09.770/EST: INFO   [uv.login] Admin logged in via local portal (remoteIp:107.126.50.200) in tomcat-HTTPS-exec-3
```

Comment: Have you used `fail2ban-regex` to test your regex? What was the result?

Comment: when I ran it no results came up

Comment: Your regex works against these log lines. What are the contents of jail.local regarding tomcat?

Comment: [tomcat] enabled = true port = 7080,7443 protocol = tcp logpath = /var/log/login.log maxretry = 4

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I came back to it this morning and purged fail2ban and all its config files. Reinstalled it and now it's working! I will just leave the above for anyone looking to do this. In my case, it was for a Ubiquiti UVC-NVR Appliance version 3.10.13.  Thanks for your help @AndroidX and @MichaelHampton! see: https://community.ui.com/questions/FAIL2BAN-on-UVC-NVR-appliance-with-Unifi-Video-3-10-13-and-Debian-9/47cd3c27-8093-4b26-907a-f61d33ae97ed